Changing circuit breakers from 8A to 16A
I'm considering replacing the circuit breaker from 8A to 16A. I've noticed there are already 16A circuit breakers installed for other parts of the house.
Currently, my heater trips the circuit breaker when set to 2000W. To prevent this, I need to set it to 1000W instead.
Is increasing the circuit breaker size a bad idea?

Please confirm your location on this planet, it will help you get better answers.

Presumably the vast majority of the world that uses 220-250VAC @ 50 hz, given the breaker amperage. Thus, appropriate wire will be sized by mm squared area. As already answered, can't be done without changing the wiring unless you like burning your house down.

Why would the builder use an 8A breaker?  They're the same price as a 16A breaker.  There must be a reason.   What is the capacity of the wires in the walls?

The only safe way to do this is to change the wires/cables to the proper size also.
Breakers are sized to prevent the wires/cables from burning/catching fire in the walls.
Most people are too cheap to use larger wires.  They use the minimum allowed for that breaker size.
